# How to get multiple text between two words in a string R?

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I am trying to get the text between two words in a sentence.
For example the sentence is -

```
x <-  "This is my first sentence and This is my second sentence"
```

Now I want output like :

```
[1] first second
```

This is what I have tried but its not working

```
gsub('^.*This is my \\s*|\\s*sentence.*$', '', x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x <-  "This is my first sentence and This is my second sentence"
gsub('.*?This is my (\\w*?) sentence.*?', '\\1 ', x)
```